# How to loop over different subdirectories and fetch different files using bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to loop over different subdirectories and fetch the files.but getting "no such file found exception"

For example : structure is like tmp/app1/app1a/some.yml and tmp/app1/app2a/some.txt
tmp/app1/app2a/dirr

Ex2

tmp/app2/app2a/some.txt
tmp/app2/app2a/dirrr
tmp/app3/some.txt

My goal is to fetch all the files which are having "debug" String.

For this I started initially to fetch a file from subdirectories.

```
Cd ~

Cd /home/dir

ls | xargs -L 1 -d '\n' | while read a 

do 
 cd $a

ls | xargs -L 1 -d '\n' | while read b

do 
 cd $b

ls | xargs -L 1 -d '\n' | while read c

do

 temp='cat $c | egrep "debug|DEBUG" | awk '{print $1}''

 echo $temp >> /dirr/example.txt

     done
   done
 done
```

This is just an example where I'm trying to find the correct loop.

Please ignore typo errors in code.

Using bash to code.

Comment: Is the incorrect use of single quotes one of the typos we should ignore?

Comment: Also, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Yes, I posted using mobile because my laptop got hang. So please ignore typos